# Error deploying Phoenix app in production

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I was trying to start a Phoenix app in production mode in a VPS (in development mode is OK) so, after compiling my application assets, I run:

```
PORT=4001 MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server
```

and I get:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application myapp: could not find application file: myapp.app
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you compiled your application in the `prod` environment?

Comment: @michalmuskala What do you mean ? I followed the Phoenix deployment guide at: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/deployment and when i did: `MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.digest`I think it compiled everything.

Comment: @PauloJaneiro I am not sure but I believe `MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.digest` has to do with your assets, you need to compile your application code, I think you need to run `mix compile`

Comment: @michalmuskala Yes, you're right! I have to run first `MIX_ENV=prod mix compile`. 1) If you know how to do it can you put this in Phoenix guides (deployment section)? 2) if you turn this into an awnser I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `prod` enviornment you need to explicitly compile your application. It won't be automatically compiled - this is one of the behaviours of the `build_embedded: true` option in your `mix.exs`.

Running `MIX_ENV=prod mix compile` before starting should fix all problems.